# I need help with Skyrim. (ps3 console). Why I can't continue?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

When open Skyrim I can only click at " new game" or downloadable content. Option" continue" or load disappeared.Option load hadn't disappeared at all. I can only see load option being grey and I can't click on it. I don't have any installed mods. Now I'm up to level 50 and I don't wanna loose all my progress. I really need your help. Can I take out CD and than return it back to console to fix my problem? Anything will help...